# HTML Table Borders

Tags: html

I am having a problem with a table, it's showing lines in the table even though no border is set and it is set to 0. The Gyazo.com link and the code is below.

http://gyazo.com/661ce70e62c77e882f85b02c4d330316 (screenshot of page)

```
<style type="text/css"><!--
table.affs td { background-color: white; margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px; padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px; } table.affs { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px; *border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing = '15px'); }
--></style>
<table class="affs" style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="700px" border="0" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.kia.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/kia.PNG" /></a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/google.png" /></a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/youtube.png" /></a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.nike.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/nike.png" /></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="http://www.jaguarpc.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/jagpc.png" /></a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.duxter.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/duxter.png" /></a></td>
<td><a href="http://www.sixpackshortcuts.com" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/sps.png" /></a></td>
<td><img src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/baeza-grey.png" href="" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/dani.png" href="" /></td>
<td><img src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/roton-grey.png" href="" /></td>
<td><img src="http://www.squareone.co/images/affiliates/talib-grey.png" href="" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm currently using the latest version of Chrome on Windows 7 and 8, I have also tried it on IE 9 and Ten on Windows 7 and 8, respectively. I have also tested it on Mac OS X Lion in Safari & Chrome. Not sure why it's doing it.

Comment: Can you provide css code?

Comment: I see borders around some of the images, but the table looks fine in IE 10 and Chrome 26: http://jsfiddle.net/SvbKt/. Unrelated, but `href` is not a valid `img` attribute in HTML 4 or 5.

Comment: Just noticed that, thanks.

Comment: Still not figuring it out, someone deleted their posts and it wasn't right, figured I'd comment and let everyone know. Still not sure why it's doing this. Forgot to add this, but this is in WordPress.

Comment: Semantically, it is not a table. Use css-float instead. It will give you less of a headache. BTW: I can't reproduce the problem either (Firefox 20.0.1), maybe you should specify what browser you are using to exhibit the problem?

Comment: @escitalopram Changed it to reflect that. Could you go ahead and give me a css-float example to use? I'm kinda rusty on CSS lol Haven't done it for a year or so.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not use `<table>` for tabular data, but for layout. This often results in layout problems, because the exact rules for table formatting are implementation dependent. Your example is a good example for CSS float, because it would still work, if you added another picture. It works like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container {overflow: hidden; width: 300px; padding: 0;}
    .element {height: 100px; width: 100px; float: left; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="element" style="background-color: #f00;">1</div>
        <div class="element" style="background-color: #ff0;">2</div>
        <div class="element" style="background-color: #f0f;">3</div>
        <div class="element" style="background-color: #0f0;">4</div>
        <div class="element" style="background-color: #0ff;">5</div>
        <div class="element" style="background-color: #00f;">6</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you feel brave, you could also try CSS3 tables, but this is not yet as widely implemented as float are. It's semantically more correct, but still has many of the drawbacks of tables being misused for something else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container { display: table; }
    .line { display: table-row; }
    .element { display: table-cell; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="line">
            <div class="element" style="background-color: #f00;">1</div>
            <div class="element" style="background-color: #ff0;">2</div>
            <div class="element" style="background-color: #f0f;">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <div class="element" style="background-color: #0f0;">4</div>
            <div class="element" style="background-color: #0ff;">5</div>
            <div class="element" style="background-color: #00f;">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If this doesn't help either, check your chrome developer tools for unwanted borders or background shining through some margin.